# How to issue 500 Internal Server Error after true debug in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I create project with Laravel 5.2, After true debug in `.env`, show `500 Internal Server Error` in `localhost:8000` ! and after false debug in `.env` dont't show any error in `localhost:8000`.

How to issue this problem?

Comment: This is something done intentionally, APP_DEBUG should be set to true on development, where you can see the errors and debug them and set to false on production as this will enable any attempts by unscrupulous people from trying to break into your system from the information they can discern from your errors.

Answer (score 0):

- Type the command `php --ini`
- Open the first file in the list with the name of `php.ini`
- search for `;display_errors = Off` and change it to `display_errors = On`

Then the blank 500 page should now contain text detailing the issue.